# 13.04 flickering cursor on cpu usage

Tags: 13.04, nvidia

I recently installed Ubuntu 13.04 onto an Acer Aspire 4755g. When idle or under low stress, the mouse pointer is completely solid and fine, however when more things start happening, it begins to flicker wildly, sometimes to the point of disappearing for a while.
For example, if I were to go to some web page, for the entire duration of the load, I would have no mouse, but once the page was loaded, it'd be back.

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 540M] (rev a1)
```

Comment: I am also having this exact problem, with Ubuntu 13.10 and with an Intel i7 and an Intel Ivybridge Mobile CPU chip.

Comment: @Shaktal yours is a non-released version of Ubuntu, here is not supported. Also, your hardware is different.

Comment: Could you add the content of `cat ~/.xsession-errors /var/log/Xorg.0.log`?

Answer (score 0):

I did not have time to do allot of research cause I had to go to work but I did run across something that might help...

The xorg.config file may need to be edited... Try the instructions below.

Type the following in a new console window:

> cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d
>
> sudo touch 10-monitor.conf
>
> sudo gedit 10-monitor.conf

Paste the following into the file, changing variables where indicated by the comments

> Section "Monitor"
>
> Identifier    "Monitor0"
>
> EndSection
>
> Section "Device"
>
> Identifier    "Device0"
>
> Driver        "nvidia" #Choose the driver used for this monitor
>
> EndSection
>
> Section "Screen"
>
> Identifier    "Screen0"  #Collapse Monitor and Device section to Screen section
>
> Device        "Device0"
>
> Monitor       "Monitor0"
>
> DefaultDepth  24 #Choose the depth (16||24)
>
> SubSection "Display"
>
> Depth     24
>
> Modes     "1680x1050" #Choose the resolution
>
> EndSubSection
>
> EndSection

Save the file.

Press CTRL + ALT + FI to enter terminal mode and type the following:

> sudo stop lightdm
>
> sudo start lightdm

Log in and notice that the cursor does not flicker any more. You may have to unplug your mouse and plug in back in to get the cursor to work. If you do not get back to the graphical mode after starting the display manager, press CTRL + ALT + F7

Answer copied from here → http://brainstep.blogspot.com/2012/02/fixing-ubuntu-issues-flickering-pointer.html

Gotta run, hope this helps... Good Luck!

Comment: Does this solution also apply for multi-monitor setups? Or will I need to define all three of my monitors individually?